# Why this method is ambiguous?

Tags: java, polymorphism, ambiguous, method-reference

I have two polymorphic methods that take two types of classes as input.

I would like the stream based on the object to do two different actions.

Instead he tells me that the method is ambiguous.

Not using streams obviously work.
My purpose is to use them.

How can I solve?

Help me, I can't understand. Thanks.

```java
Stream.of(1,"Text").forEach(Test::method);


static void method(Integer i){
    System.out.println("i");
}

static void method(String i){
    System.out.println("s");
}
```

Comment: "Not using streams obviously work." I don't think so. Show me how you would "not use streams" and make this work.

Answer (score 2):

If you assigned the stream to a local variable you'll see that type of `Stream.of(1,"Text")` is `Stream<Object>`

```
Stream<Object> x = Stream.of(1,"Text");
```

Thus the type of the method that is needed for the forEach is:

```
static void method(Object obj){
    System.out.println("Object is: "+obj);
}
```

If you had used `Stream.of(1,2)` or `Stream.of("Hello", "Text")` then the method calls would resolve as you expected.

Comment: The stream has the type `Stream<Object>`, *because* you’re assigning it to a variable of type `Stream<Object>`. Try `Stream<Serializable> x = Stream.of(1,"Text");` or `Stream<Comparable<?>> x = Stream.of(1,"Text");`…

Comment: @Holger Well spotted - JDK17 suggests Stream<ConstantDesc> and Stream<Constable> are also valid assignments.

Comment: Yes, since JDK 12

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method who accept Object parameter, and go with this approach :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
static void method(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof String)
        method((String)o);
    if(o instanceof Integer)
        method((Integer)o);
}

static void method(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("i");
}

static void method(String i) {
    System.out.println("s");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(1, "Text").forEach(element -> {
        Test.method( element );
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the type of elements in `Stream.of(1, "Text", null)` is the common super type of all three arguments, a method accepting an argument of `Object` type may be implemented to dispatch the call to appropriate overloaded `method` (`null` values should be handled to map to some specific method too):

```java
Stream.of(1,"Text", null).forEach(Test::method);

static void method(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        method((Integer) o);
    } else if (o instanceof String || null == o) {
        method((String) o);
    } else {
        method(o.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i
s
s
```

---

Regarding the statement:

> Not using streams obviously work.

This does not seem to be true.

If a raw list/array is created and used instead of the Stream, a similar issue occurs:

```java
List list = Arrays.asList(1, "Text", null);
// list.forEach(Test::method); // fails too, same error as below
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    method(list.get(i));
}
```

In this case error would look like:

```
/Test.java:10: error: no suitable method found for method(Object)
    method(list.get(i));
    ^
    method Test.method(Integer) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Integer)
    method Test.method(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to String)
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Java only resolves overloads at compile time. You seem to want `Test::method` to resolve to `method(Integer)` (first overload) when iterating over `1`, and resolve to `method(String)` (second overload) when iterating over `"Text"`. That's not possible, `Test::method` can only resolve to one thing.

The error message is a bit confusing indeed. The problem is not that it is ambiguous between the two methods. The problem is that since you have both strings and integers in the stream, `forEach` expects you to give it a method that can accept *both* strings and integers (or more accurately, a common supertype between `String` and `Integer`, since there's no union types in Java).

```
static void method(Object o){

}
```

But neither of the overloads of `method` that you have accepts both strings and integers.

To do what you want, you must check the type at runtime, and call the overload manually:

```
Stream.of(1,"Text").forEach(x -> {
    if (x instanceof Integer) {
        method((Integer)x);
    } else if (x instanceof String) {
        method((String)x);
    }
});
```

I would suggest that you *don't* put strings and integers together in the same stream.

The situation would be different if the types involved are not `String` and `Integer`, but classes that you wrote. Because then you can write `method` as an instance method in a common superclass. Unlike overload resolution, choosing which overridden implementation of an instance method to run *is* done at runtime.

```
class Superclass {
  public void method() {
    
  }
}

class BaseClass1 extends Superclass {

  @Override
  public void method() {
    System.out.println("i");
  }
}

class BaseClass2 extends Superclass {

  @Override
  public void method() {
    System.out.println("s");
  }
}

// ...

Stream.of(new BaseClass1(), new BaseClass2()).forEach(Superclass::method);
```

Comment: “The error message is a bit confusing indeed”—and not reproducible. Neither javac nor Eclipse produce the error message the OP has posted…

Comment: @Holger Huh, I can reproduce it with IntelliJ. I guess this is another one of those confusing things that IntelliJ does then.

Comment: That’s strange; as far as I know, IntelliJ doesn’t have its own compiler but settles atop the others. So it must have redacted the error feedback. Do you know which compiler and version has been used when you got the error message?

Comment: @Holger Yeah, I would assume so. OP's error can be seen if you hover over the red underline, but if you actually click the green run button, it will change to what `javac` would show.

Comment: @Holger I'm using IntelliJ 2021.2 CE, Build #iC-212.4742.92.